# IIS - Complete Certificate Request when Create Certificate Request was from another server

Tags: iis, iis-8, iis-8.5

To be clear, I have both the csr and cer files.

The csr was generated on my desktop.  The cer was generated by our CA.  I can import the site.cer file file but it doesn't show up in IIS because the csr is missing.

Is there a way to import that csr into IIS so that the Certificate is viewable in the Server Certificates?  Currently I see it in Personal.

I tried running the following but it errors on the Smart Card which I do not have.

`certutil -repairstore "my" <serialnumber>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the following on the computer where the CSR was created:

```
certreq -accept filename.cer
```

You may then export the certificate to a PFX file on that computer, and import it to the computer personal store on the IIS computer.  Ensure you include the private key in the export.

Comment: thank you!  as soon as I did this I just exported from my desktop with private key and then was able to import to the server IIS instance.